# Cast an entire webpage to tv?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, chromecast

I need to cast an entire webpage (which includes images, videos, iframes and carousels) to a chromecast enabled TV.

Once loaded, the webpage is auto scroll enabled and hence keeps showing few images, videos and iframes (think of it like a looped slideshow).

I know there's an option in the chrome browser itself to cast a tab/entire desktop, but it would require my laptop/computer screen to be open all the time.

I also came across chromecast for web app docs: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender/integrate , but as far as I can figure out, it will help only to cast videos but not iframes/carousels embedded in my website.

Any suggestions how to achieve this? The requirement is to show an advertisement kind of data to the TV in every 3 hours. All this cannot be automated fully I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. You just need to create a custom receiver app, which is basically just an HTML page that implements the cast receiver framework javascript. https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/basic